# Virtual path but different content

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make a really simple website with multiple pages. I've been coding in HTML for a while now, but just started to experiment with PHP.

My page setup goes like this:

`Rootfolder/settings/language` -- In there, I just put a index.php
`Rootfolder/settings/Privacy` -- In there, I also just put a index.php

In this particular case, I could indeed use rename the files to language.php/Privacy.php to reduce space. But that is still not what I'm expecting from a lightweight website.

In order to make it easier for myself, I use `include_once` to include the header, meta data (I know it's not smart, because of SEO reasons), footers and other stuff that is very general and has to be the same across the whole website. But here is the thing; I really think that this method is way to complicated. Every time I need a new file, I just have to duplicate the page that includes the `include_once` files, and then change the content of it. Same goes for the titles.

So, what I'm looking for is a page setup like this (1) :
Rootfolder/Pages/index.php -- Inside that index.php, the content has to change dynamically. The visitors still have to go to: `https://domain.tld/settings/language` but the server has to decode it to the setup from (1) and change the content to the original content of `Rootfolder/settings/language/index.php`.

In the past, I've downloaded some PHP scripts, which all included title setups like: `<title> $title - $SiteName </title>` (or something like that) - So it must be possible to change content dynamically.

The problem is... I really don't know where to start. Does anyone has good/lightweight solution for this?

Comment: It seems to me you're looking for a way to handle different languages, without creating multiple files?

Comment: Not really languages, that was a example. I'm looking for different content without having to create multiple physical root folders.

Comment: It's still a bit unclear, but you could have a Database driven platform that pulls in content to a page. At the bare minimum, you could pass in $_GET params and have the query fetch content based on your needs.

Comment: Sounds like what I need, do you maybe have an example?

Comment: No, as the code behind that would be very opinionated, and require a lot of knowledge about how you'd intend to setup the DB and do the routing.

I'd suggest looking into something along the lines of how a blog is coded in order to get a grasp on how this could translate to your needs.